Bernoulli equation and gravitational potential energy
I know that the Bernoulli equation preserves the mechanical energy of the fluid and that the sum of pressure, gravitational potential energy, and kinetic energy is constant. I found the Magnus effect applied to the Bernoulli equation and understood that the direction of the Magnus force acts from high to low pressure.
But why not consider gravitational potential energy?
I don't think there's a need to consider it because the flow of fluid is constant in the wings of the aircraft.
However, in ball games, the position changes from time to time, so shouldn't gravity potential energy be considered?
Or is it not considered because the effect of gravitational potential energy is small?
When I learned the Magnus effect, I learned it as a soccer ball. I learned that when a soccer ball rotates in the same direction as a fluid flow, it speeds up and reduces pressure according to the Bernoulli equation.
However, we find that the gravitational potential energy is not taken into account in this situation.
So when I asked elsewhere, they answered that the gravitational potential energy change of the soccer ball is not big, so they are not considering it.
In the end, like the wings of an aircraft, the main fluid flow in the ball is horizontal, so the gravitational potential energy can be ignored.
But what I'm curious about is if it's really negligible and doesn't have to be considered, or if other mechanisms work.
I only know the Bernoulli equation for fluid dynamics and the extent of Pascal's principle, and I only know that the Navier-Stokes equation is similar to the Bernoulli equation.

Gravitational potential energy isn't small in this application of the Magnus effect - Backspin Basketball Flies Off Dam

I think the image presented is because the vertical effect is larger than the horizontal effect. This is because the gravitational potential energy is the energy acting vertically.

A good example, but I wanted to know the effect of gravitational potential energy in horizontal motion.

You're on the right track with the suggestion that gravitation is a small effect in this case. It's possible to make a simplified argument for why this is expected. If we consider the changes in hydrostatic pressure as air flows around a ball in motion we can see that $\Delta p \sim \rho g \Delta z \sim 1$ Pa (assuming the ball is $\sim 10$ cm in size and density is $\rho \sim 1$ kg/m$^3$). By contrast the dynamic pressure associated with the flow around the ball will be $\frac{\rho v^2}{2} \sim 200$ Pa (assuming $v \sim 20$ m/s).
The above compares the buoyant force and aerodynamic forces acting on a ball. A more careful analysis would consider only those associated with the rotation.
A possible misconception from your question is that you need to consider the change in the ball's altitude across its trajectory to determine the forces acting on it at a particular point in time. Although the change in the ball's potential energy over time may be significant, this does not mean that potential energy changes in the air flowing around the ball will significantly alter that flow at any instant. The relevant length scale is the size of the ball, not the trajectory.

Fluid mechanics is complicated. All the processes you refer to have different settings, and so different versions of the equations such as Bernoulli or Euler apply. You need to be far more specific as to the exact situations that you are interested in.   Bernoulli is is often horribly misapplied because people apply equations for designed specific settings  to situations in which those  assumptions no longer apply.

I checked. I'll correct the question
